# java - Splitting unknown amount of strings per line

Tags: java, string, split

I have a text file structured like this:

```
    class Object0 extends Object1
    class Object2 extends Object3
    class Object1
    class Object4 extends Object1
    class Object3
```

I want to split each string and store it. I know how to do this when the number of strings is known on each line, however in this case there can either be two or four words on a given line.

Here's what I have for splitting when the number of strings are known:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File f = new File("test.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                String[] details = line.split(" ");
                String classIdentifier = details[0];
                String classNameFirst = details[1];
             // String classExtends = details[2];
             // String classNameSecond = details[3];
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Use `details.length` to check if it's 2 or 4.

Comment: What's your definition of a `working` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop on the `details` array to get each splitted string no matter how many they are. Plus I made some changes in your `main` method to make it more correct (added a finally clause to close the `Scanner` resource).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        File f = new File("test.txt");
        sc = new Scanner(f);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] details = line.split(" ");
            for(String str: details) {
                //variable str contains each value of the string split
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration you can check if there are two more words, this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        File f = new File("test.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] details = line.split(" ");
            String classIdentifier = details[0];
            String classNameFirst = details[1];
            // this can be done because you declared there
            // can be only 2 or 4 words per line
            if (details.length==4) {
                String classExtends = details[2];
                String classNameSecond = details[3];
            }
            // do something useful here with extracted fields (store?)
            // before they get destroyed in the next iteration
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```